# My HP does not boot after fresh Ubuntu 22.04 install

Tags: 22.04, hp

I have a HP ProBook 6460b laying around. I FRESHLY installed Ubuntu 22.04.3 Desktop, and then at the reboot stage, reboots completely fine, and it gave me this error:

```
BootDevice Not Found
Please install an operating system on your hard disk.
Hard Disk - (3F0)
```

That literally makes me want to throw it out of the window.

(Written to USB with balenaEtcher)

Comment: You provided few specifics; Ubuntu 22.04 without details as to Server?, Desktop? 22.04? 22.04.1? ... 22.04.3?  Ubuntu 22.04 through 22.04.2 now have *revoked* keys on them (*which should impact the install media as well*) with the newer key on 22.04.3 ISOs. You can also write the ISO to install media in ways that will cause it to fail to boot as you indicate (*you didn't specify how you wrote ISO to media; as incorrect writes of ISO can trigger boot [records] being written to incorrect device*) as well as other possible causes too.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows)

Comment: Nope, the laptop does not have any OS installed, + Ubuntu 20.04 Desktop works perfectly fine.

Comment: After trying to install Ubuntu 23.10.1, now, even Boot Selection does not work.